# String pool vs Constant pool

Tags: java, string, jvm, constants

Let's look at the folloing code snippet:

```
  String s1 = "Hello";
  String s2 = "Hello";
```

Both variables refer to the same object due to interning. Since strings are immutable, only one object is created and both refer to the same object.

A `constant pool` is also something, which holds all the constants (integer, string, etc.) that are declared in a class. It is specific to each class.

```
 System.out.println("Hello");  // I believe this Hello is different from above.
```

**Questions:**

1. Does `string pool` refer to the pool of a constant string object in the constant pool?
2. If yes, is *String pool* common throughout the whole application or specific to a class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457146/regarding-java-string-constant-pool?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should we use intern method of String on String constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-constants)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> My questions are,
>
> 1. Does string pool refers to the pool of constant string object in the constant pool?

No.

"Constant pool" refers to a specially formatted collection of bytes in a class file that has meaning to the Java class loader.  The "strings" in it are [serialized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization), they are not Java objects.  There are also many kinds of constants, not just strings in it.

See [Chapter 4.4 the constant pool table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4)

> Java Virtual Machine instructions do not rely on the run-time layout of classes, interfaces, class instances, or arrays. Instead, instructions refer to symbolic information in the `constant_pool` table.

In contrast, the "String pool" is used at runtime (not just during class loading), **contains only strings**, and the "strings" in the string pool are java objects.
The "string pool" is a thread-safe weak-map from `java.lang.String` instances to `java.lang.String` instances used to intern strings.

[Chapter 3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) says

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class `String` (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the **same** instance of class `String`. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Comment: Where is this string pool stored? As link http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/ claims that interned Strings are stored in heap. So is it the same heap as where other objects are located or different? Any links to javadocs or java specification would be appreciated.

Comment: @nanosoft, With a generational garbage collector, new objects are allocated in the [nursery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html#wp1085825), but interned strings are usually long lived, so an implementation could skip the nursery for strings allocated by class loaders.  Whether a JVM does this is an implementation decision, and is not mandated by the *Java Virtual Machine Specification*.  The *Java **Language** Specification* is the other half of the Java specification, but mostly delegates to the JVM spec on memory management matters.

Comment: Are you sure that String Pool is a weak map? There is no any information in the JVM spec that would claim this. How did you find out this? Can you provide some references to the openjdk source code or any other official references that would proof this?

Comment: @EugeneMaysyuk iirc, weak semantics aren't speced but are de facto. 
 See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/910e24afc502/src/share/vm/classfile/stringTable.cpp#l193

Answer (score 3):

There is only one string pool, and all string literals are automatically interned.
Also, there are other pools for autoboxing and such.

The constant pool is where those literals are put for the class.

Answer (score 0):

constans_pool(all constans, including Strings) is a data structure in class file(out of JVM).
When class file is loaded into JVM, then constans_pool -> run-time constans_pool(General), in hotspot & SE8:

1. Strings in constans_pool will be stored in Heap, and we call it string-pool;  https://openjdk.org/jeps/122    https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/HotSpot/Caching+Java+Heap+Objects
2. the other data in constans_pool will be stored in native-memory(Metaspace),and we call it run-time constans_pool(Special).