# String Memory Model - java6

Tags: java, string, memory-management

As clear from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java), the actual characters that comprise a `String` in Java are actually stored in the `private final char value[];` character array.

Can someone please help me in understanding the following questions for an expression `String text = "Hello World";`

1. What is actually stored in **StringPool** ? I've read many places that its the `String` literal. If thats the case, what exactly is the difference between a String Object and a String literal as both must be backed by a `char[]`
2. If the String reference is marked as Constant (final), will it be stored in the `Runtime Constant Pool` inside the `Method Area` as well ?
3. As mentioned [here](https://dzone.com/articles/string-memory-internals), the actual `char[] value` is created on the heap only. So when `intern()` method is called on a `String` object created using `new` operator, what will be copied to the **StringPool** (assuming its not the character array) ?

Edit :

As mentioned [here](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6988220), StringPool is implemented as a HashMap. So what could be the key and value for the same ? It appears that the value cannot be the `char[] value` as the same is created on the Heap.

Comment: String literal is compile-time artifact, mostly. The runtime representation of it is still `String` object.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov : If String literal is just a compile time artifact, then how is it moved to StringPool  when intern method is called on a String created using new operator as it should not be there at all ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-literals explains it well

Comment: @Sumit, I was anwering on the difference between string object and string literal: there is none, at runtime. At runtime, both are just `String` objects. Certain number of those are created from literals, but that's about it. Javadoc for `intern()` is also pretty clear as to what is actually stored in the pool and is returned returned from that method. It's not concerned with `char[]` inside string, because a `String` is not actually required to have that array inside it, that's just its implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

No expert at this but I will give it a shot.

```
String text = "Hello World";
```

[image]

[image]

lcd(load a constant) look ups the string in a constant pool table. found #2 which has an address of "Hello Word" which is at #14

Reference:[What is the purpose of the Java Constant Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209952/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-java-constant-pool)

Reference:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/it-haggar_bytecode/#opcode

Comment: But as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252767/string-pool-vs-constant-pool), a StringPool is different than a ConstantPool. The load constant command (lcd) refers to the constants in Constant Pool symbol table but how the String literal, String Object and Underlying Character array are handled memory wise ?